# How do I get a Kafka message before the @KafkaListener method?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My task is to get the Kafka message before the method with the @KafkaListner annotation, check the correlationId and requestId headers in it. If they're present, flush them to MDC or generate them otherwise.

And my question is how to get Kafka message with headers before method with the @KafkaListner?

Comment: Cant you do it in that method?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to write your own `ConsumerInterceptor` following instructions from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#interceptors). 
*Apache Kafka provides a mechanism to add interceptors to producers and consumers. These objects are managed by Kafka, not Spring, and so normal Spring dependency injection won’t work for wiring in dependent Spring Beans. However, you can manually wire in those dependencies using the interceptor config() method. The following Spring Boot application shows how to do this by overriding boot’s default factories to add some dependent bean into the configuration properties.*

ConsumerFactory definition:

```
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<?, ?> kafkaConsumerFactory(SomeBean someBean) {
        Map<String, Object> consumerProperties = new HashMap<>();
        // consumerProperties.put(..., ...)
        // ...
        consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG, MyConsumerInterceptor.class.getName());
        consumerProperties.put("some.bean", someBean);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProperties);
    }
```

Interceptor definition:

```
public class MyConsumerInterceptor implements ConsumerInterceptor<String, String> {

    private SomeBean bean;

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
        this.bean = (SomeBean) configs.get("some.bean");
    }

    @Override
    public ConsumerRecords<String, String> onConsume(ConsumerRecords<String, String> records) {
        this.bean.someMethod("consumer interceptor");
        return records;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCommit(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets) {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

}
```

Comment: You could also add a `RecordInterceptor` to the listener container factory if you want to do everything via Spring. It will get one record at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can I explicitly not add `properties.put(INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG, KafkaConsumerInterceptor.class.getName());` to consumerFactory?

Comment: No. The RecordInterceptor is a Spring concept. The problem with ConsumerInterceptor is that it gets multiple records at once so won’t help with MDC. The RecordInterceptor is called by Spring for each record.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `RecordInterceptor` to the listener container (or factory that creates it).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can I explicitly not add `properties.put(INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG,RecordInterceptor.class.getName());` to consumerFactory?

Comment: No. The RecordInterceptor is a Spring concept. The problem with ConsumerInterceptor is that it gets multiple records at once so won’t help with MDC. The RecordInterceptor is called by Spring for each record.

Comment: This is bad news. Is there any way to intercept the headers at the kafka NetworkClient level?

Comment: Why is it "bad" news? It's easy enough to add the interceptor to the container or the factory that creates it. I don't see how doing anything at the network level will help, particularly with MDC since a) there will be multiple records and b) it's on a different thread. If you need help configuring it, edit the question to show your current listener and configuration and I'll tell you how to configure the interceptor.

Comment: I have a question unrelated to the current topic. When I switched to debug logging level, I saw many log events:

`[Consumer clientId=consumer-some-app, groupId=some-app Sending METADATA request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=12, clientId=some-app, correlationId=2)` from NetworkClient.

Is it possible to get correlationId?

Comment: Don't ask unrelated questions in comments; ask a new question and explain why you need it.